# How can i add listviewitemeventargs as a argument in onitemupdated event of a listview?

Tags: asp.net, listview, textbox

Following is my listview markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SNO" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnItemCreated="DateCalculation" OnItemUpdated="Update">
```

As you can see i have two events **DateCalculation** and **UpdateButton**. Date Calculation event is below:-

```
 protected void DateCalculation(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
    {
        TextBox txtbox1 = e.Item.FindControl("DateTakenPlaceTextBox") as TextBox;
        txtbox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

    }
}

Now when i try to add similar event to Update i.e.

protected void Update(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
    {
        TextBox txtbox2 = e.Item.FindControl("AmountTextBox") as TextBox;
        if (txtbox2.Text == null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I get following error :
**No overload for 'Update' matches delegate

'System.EventHandler'**

Does this mean I have to write eventargs instead of Listviewitemeventargs?? I want to access listviewitems so i need  **Listviewitemeventargs**. Can anyone suggest what to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [ListViewUpdatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdatedeventargs.aspx) which contains properties you can use, like [NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdatedeventargs.newvalues.aspx), [OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdatedeventargs.newvalues.aspx) and [AffectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdatedeventargs.affectedrows.aspx).

**Edit**
To prevent null and empty values you can use the [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemupdating.aspx) event instead. You need to check this *before* the items are updated. Otherwise it's too late.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SNO" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
              OnItemCreated="DateCalculation" OnItemUpdating="Updating">
```

```cs
protected void Updating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  // Cancel the update operation if any of the fields is empty or null.
  foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.NewValues)
  {
    // Check if the value is null or empty.
    if (de.Value == null || de.Value.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
    {
      Message.Text = "Cannot set a field to an empty value.";
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to just check a specific field for null or empty:

```cs
var val = e.NewValues["Amount"];
if (val == null || val.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
{
  Message.Text = "Cannot set a field to an empty value.";
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: How can i retrieve the fields which are affected??? I have a textbox in my Listview named Amount. Now I don't want this Amount textbox to be null which accidentally a user can do. What should I do??       Sani Huttunen